# Comparing columns in two different dataframes for matching values Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Here is what my two dataframes look like:

**DF1**

```
NAME   EMAIL                ID
Mark   mark@gmail.com      8974
Sam    sam@gmail.com       9823
June   june@gmail.com      0972
David  david@gmail.com     2143
```

**DF2**

```
ID     ROLE-ID
2143      22
0972      34
8974      98
9823      54
```

What I need to help doing:

I need to COMPARE the ID column for both dataframes and if the ID from DF1 MATCHES with the ID of DF2, I need to replace the ID column in DF1 with the respective ROLE-ID from DF2.

The output would look like this:

**Updated DF1**

```
NAME   EMAIL               ROLE-ID
Mark   mark@gmail.com        98
Sam    sam@gmail.com         54
June   june@gmail.com        34
David  david@gmail.com       22
```

I am using the Pandas library and tried the merge function with conditions but it didnt work

```
    print(pd.merge(df1, df2, on=(df1['Id'] == df2[])))
```

Comment: Please include the code you tried.

Comment: The goal isnt simply just to merge the two dataframes. The "ID" for both DFs has to match before it is replaced

Comment: That is the whole purpose of joining. It's simply `df1.merge(df2, on='ID')`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left')
df[['NAME', 'EMAIL', 'ROLE-ID']]
```

It gives the following:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lToRw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You did not exactly state what should happen if id is not found or is avail multiple times this may not be 100% what you want. It will leave the id untouched then.B ut guess otherwise its what you wanted.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,'a'],
                    [7,'b'],
                    [3,'e'],
                    [2,'c']], columns=['id', 'name'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],
                    [3,8],
                    [2,10]], columns=['id', 'role'])

# collect roles
roles = []
for id in df1.loc[:, 'id']:
    indices = df2.loc[:,'id'] == id
    if np.sum(indices) == 1:
        roles.append(df2.loc[indices, 'role'].iloc[0])
    else:
        # take id if role id is not given
        roles.append(id)  # could also be None if not wanted

# add role id col
df1.loc[:,'role-id'] = roles

# delete old id
del df1['id']

print(df1)
```

DF1:

```
   id name
0   1    a
1   7    b
2   3    e
3   2    c
```

DF2:

```
   id  role
0   1     2
1   3     8
2   2    10
```

Output

```
  name  role-id
0    a        2
1    b        7
2    e        8
3    c       10
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a `merge` problem

```
pd.merge(df2, df1, how='inner')
```

Comment: you can also include `on` variable `pd.merge(df2, df1, how='inner', on='ID')`

Comment: Did you these answers? Because they are both wrong

Comment: I might have misunderstood the problem. Could you help me understand why I was wrong?